# Hide Data Labels in Pie Chart below 400px width - Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to use the new responsive options in Highcharts to hide data labels on a pie chart when the charts width gets below 400px.

My responsive code is as follows:

```
responsive: {
   rules: [{
       condition: {
           maxWidth: 300
       },
       plotOptions: {
           pie: {
               allowPointSelect: true,
               cursor: 'pointer',
               dataLabels: {
                   enabled: false,
                   format: '<b>{point.name}</b>:{point.percentage:.1f} %',
                   style: {
                       color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }]
}
```

and is meant to set the dataLabels enabled to false below 400px. I've attempted this here http://jsfiddle.net/chv4ux0z/ but to no avail, does anyone know what I'm doing wrong, I've followed the Highcharts examples but just cant seem to get this right?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you should be able to add your plotOptions inside responsive.rules.chartOptions object. Then your chart should work correctly:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/responsive.rules.chartOptions

```
  responsive: {
    rules: [{
      condition: {
        maxWidth: 400
      },
      chartOptions: {
        plotOptions: {
          pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: false,
              format: '<b>{point.name}</b>:         {point.percentage:.1f} %',
              style: {
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }]
  }
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/chv4ux0z/2/

Comment: John, could you please tell me what is not working in my example? Maybe you have issues with http/https? http://jsfiddle.net/chv4ux0z/4/

Comment: The labels are appearing with your condition.

Comment: Are you sure that your chart is smaller than 400px? The chart is resizable so it may be bigger or smaller than 400px. In my case I have two charts, one in case when container is bigger than 400px and one when container is smaller than 400px. Could you please give me some more details about your case? What browser are you using?